# How to create an output file without running arguments in java?

Tags: java, output

So I have a java program that is fully working but the results are so massive I want to put the results on a text file so I can see it clearly and so it can all fit. How do I put the output results of my program on a text file without having to run arguments?

Comment: If you have the source code you can redirect all the output from the console to a file with a call to `System.setOut` at the start.

Comment: So where will the output file be located if I call System.setOut

Comment: ok so i did 
     FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream("results.txt");
     System.setOut(new PrintStream(f));
but the results text was blank

Comment: @user3600008 check my example

Comment: You correctly created a `FileOutputStream`, but used a `PrintStream`. Use `System.setOut(f)`.

Comment: @GabrielNegut I am still getting an error saying:
Run.java:21: setOut(java.io.PrintStream) in java.lang.System cannot be applied to (java.io.FileOutputStream)

Comment: My mistake, `setOut` takes a `PrintStream`, not an `OutputStream`. Use `System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("results.txt")))`.

Comment: @GabrielNegut I ran that and it created an output file but it's blank

Comment: You called `setOut` right at the beginning?

Comment: its the last thing i called in my main method

Comment: @GabrielNegut You were right i should have called it at the very beginning. It works now thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the output to a file by changing the System,out from the monitor to a file.

Example:

```
 System.setOut(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("file.txt")));
 System.out.println("Hello, this is printed in a file called file.txt");
```

Comment: I want to put the results of my program on an output file, not a string

Comment: @user3600008 This will redirect all the System.out from your monitor to a file, so output displayed on your screen will now be displayed on a file called file.txt

Comment: I ran it and the text is blank and it's saying that 
   results.txt"
   may have been edited outside of jGRASP.
   Modification time has changed, but line count has not.
   Scroll and cursor positions, and fold, bookmark, and breakpoint
   positions may not be as expected.

Comment: Is the file open or used at the same time that you're trying to print output to it ? @user3600008

Comment: Nope it creates a brand new output file